# Devise JWT Test Rspec, help-me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec, tdd

I am trying to get devise and devise-jwt gems to work so I can implement Authorization into my API only Rails app.

I have installed both devise and devise-jwt gems.

I followed the instructions on this blog post:
https://medium.com/@mazik.wyry/rails-5-api-jwt-setup-in-minutes-using-devise-71670fd4ed03

I have implemented the request specs that the author has included in his post and I can't get it approved on "Deleted",
I have to pass the authorizate token on delete, but I'm not getting it.
Any suggestion?

```
require 'rails_helper'
require "json"

RSpec.describe "POST /users", type: :request do
  
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
    let(:url) { '/users/sign_in' }
    let(:params) do
      {
        user: {
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password
        }
      }
    end

    context 'when params are correct' do
      before do
        post url, params: params.to_json, headers: { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json' }
      end
  
      it 'returns 200' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
      end
  
      it 'returns JTW token in authorization header' do
        expect(response.headers['authorization']).to be_present
      end
  
    
    end
  
    context 'when login params are incorrect' do
      before { post url }
      
      it 'returns unathorized status' do
        expect(response.status).to eq 401
      end
    end
    
  end
  
  RSpec.describe 'DELETE /logout', type: :request do
    let(:url) { '/users/sign_out' }

   
    it 'returns 204, no content' do
      delete url
      expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
    end
  end
```

I need to pass the user's token on delete, any suggestions on how I can be doing this?

Comment: It doesn't look like your user is signed in for your delete describe. The before block where you do sign in, is in the post describe block.

Comment: It runs all the tests except the delete one.